# Compare ODBC settings across multiple database servers

Tags: odbc, datasource, cluster-computing

I've run into this problem with my three-node SQL Cluster, though it's not unique to clusters. We have a dozen different ODBC drivers installed, both x86 and x64 versions, and we're constantly finding instances where some nodes in our cluster has either a different version of the driver, are missing the driver, or it's not configured properly. Especially in a cluster, it's critical that different nodes all have the same configurations, or jobs can fail unexpectedly on one node and run fine on another, and it leads to hours of frustration.

Is there a tool out there that will compare the installed/configured ODBC drivers and data sources and produce a report of what's out of sync? I've considered writing something in the past to do this, but haven't gotten around to it. If it's an issue for others and there's not a tool that does it, I'll put one together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the information related to your ODBC settings is stored in the registry, all together. Since nobody else knows of an app to compare these settings, I'll throw one together and post it on my website, putting a link here.

If you want to compare the settings yoursef, they're stored at:

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ (your data sources)
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ (your installed providers)

Also, it's worth noting that if you're on an x64 machine, there are both x64 and x86 ODBC drivers and data sources, and they're stored separately - in this case, check out the accepted answer on the following post to see which location you should be checking in:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/92f962d6-7f5e-4e62-ac0a-b8b0c9f552a3